# Regex: How can I find number and character between { }

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like:`$str='&%#^*@\"~ \'a4{=s{sa*}7s*&$db{abc654d3ws67}d(*$%#$c6'#^*@"~ \'a4\"';` .

I need to find what is not like `{abc654d3ws67}` as `$needle` from that string and preplace it by `bin2hex($needle)`.

Example: `bin2hex('#')`.

Comment: Did you bother trying anything?

Comment: I tried `explode('{')` and `explode('}')` but it seem to be a bad way

Comment: So `{abc654d3ws67}` becomes #? I'm not understanding the question I guess.

Comment: Does `{abc654d3ws67}` only occur once in the string?

Comment: No it doesn't, it occur more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the wording this is what it sounds like you're looking for:

```
<?php

$str='&%#^*@\"~ \'a4{=s{sa*}7s*&$db{abc654d3ws67}d(*$%#$c6\'#^*@"~ \'a4\"';
$pattern = '!^(.+)({abc654d3ws67})(.+)$!';
$tstring = preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches);
$newstring = bin2hex($matches[1]).$matches[2].bin2hex($matches[3]);

echo "<pre>$newstring</pre>";
?>
```

output is:

> 2625235e2a405c227e202761347b3d737b73612a7d37732a26246462{abc654d3ws67}64282a24252324633627235e2a40227e202761345c22

The old code threw a T_LNUMBER warning.

**Update** For hex only:

```
<?php

$str='&%#^*@\"~ \'a4{=s{sa*}7s*&$db{abc654d3ws67}d(*$%#$c6\'#^*@"~ \'a4\"';
$pattern = '!^(.+)(abc654d3ws67)(.+)$!';
$tstring = preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches);
$newstring = bin2hex($matches[1]).$matches[2].bin2hex($matches[3]);

echo "<pre>$newstring</pre>";
?>
```

output is:

> 2625235e2a405c227e202761347b3d737b73612a7d37732a26246462abc654d3ws6764282a24252324633627235e2a40227e202761345c22

Answer (score 3):

Find every occurrence of `{`, followed by any number of letters or digits, followed by a `}`.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback( '/\{([^a-z0-9]+)\}/i', function( $match) { 
    return bin2hex( $match[1]); 
}, $str);
```

Comment: I think that we need to put '!' in somewhere because I want to find what not like `{abc654d3ws67}`, thank you any way!

Comment: What is "not like"? If you want to exclude letters and digits, I can edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English! Yeah, I want to exclude letters and digits and `{` and `}` in `{abc654d3ws67}` too.

Comment: Try again, I edited my answer and negated the character group.

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV, in this case, I have the curly braces in my string. And I finding the another part which don't containt`{abc654d3ws67}`. Sorry for my bad English again!